# how to avoid freezing when download file using wininet

Tags: delphi, wininet

iam using wininet to download image and save it to memory stream here is my procedure

```
procedure DownloadToStream(const Url: string; ms: TMemoryStream);
var
  hSession     : HINTERNET;
  hService     : HINTERNET;
  lpBuffer     : array[0..1023] of Byte;
  dwBytesRead  : DWORD;
  dwBytesAvail : DWORD;
  dwTimeOut    : DWORD;
begin
  hSession := InternetOpen('usersession', INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, nil, nil, 0);
  if not Assigned(hSession) then Exit;
  try
    hService := InternetOpenUrl(hSession, PChar(Url), nil, 0, 0, 0);
    if hService = nil then
      Exit;
    try
      dwTimeOut := 60000;
      InternetSetOption(hService, INTERNET_OPTION_RECEIVE_TIMEOUT, @dwTimeOut, SizeOf(dwTimeOut));
      if InternetQueryDataAvailable(hService, dwBytesAvail, 0, 0) then
      repeat
        if not InternetReadFile(hService, @lpBuffer[0], SizeOf(lpBuffer), dwBytesRead) then
          Break;
        if dwBytesRead <> 0 then
          ms.WriteBuffer(lpBuffer[0], dwBytesRead);
      until dwBytesRead = 0;
    finally
      InternetCloseHandle(hService);
    end;
  finally
    InternetCloseHandle(hSession);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    DownloadToStream('imageurl, ms);
    ms.Position := 0;
    //do whatever you want with ms
  finally
    ms.Free;
  end;
end;
```

it working fine and no freeze while downloading small images but when its comes to large images the application is freezing until downloading is done , how to avoid that ?

Comment: You should spend a little time learning how the Windows message loop works and observe that your function is called from the message loop.

Comment: If you want something good to read about the windows message loop, this is an excellent article : http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447

Comment: thank you very much for direction , i used `Application.ProcessMessages;` between repeat until to handle the freeze

Comment: @DelphiStudent Now... just beware : http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm  `ProcessMessages` is a quick and dirty fix, but it's dirty programming and if you're building anything other than a mash-up test application it can eventually come back to bite you.

Comment: yes you are correct i possible will move the code from DownloadToStream to a thread OnExecute event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is freezing because the call doesn't return until the download is done, and as you already know from web browsing, sometimes that can take a long time.  While that's happening, your program is not running the normal event loop and processing input.

If you want to make it work right, you'll need to do the download in a different thread.  Multithreading can be very tricky, but with the right libraries it becomes a lot simpler.  For something like this, I'd suggest looking at [the Async/Await functionality in OmniThreadLibrary.](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/07/asyncawait-in-delphi.html)

Comment: thank you for answer , if i use `idhttp` would be much easier ?

Comment: @DelphiStudent: Not really. `TIdHTTP` still downloads things synchronously.  If you want to keep your UI responsive, you need to perform long-running tasks asynchronously.  OmniThreadLibrary can really help with getting that right.

Comment: Doesen't indy also support multithreading meaning that its code can be executed in additional threads? I do know this is supported with TIdTCPServer for processing received commands but I'm not sure for other Indy components.